# write and save a text file using javascript in webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, windows-forms-designer

i am Developing a tool in windows form where i am using a webbrowser control

Need help to write data from a javacript. basically i need to create a text file and save the file without the download prompt or user interface. file should be downloaded automatically. so far i have tried

```
 function saveTextAsFile(text)
{
var textToWrite = text;

var fileNameToSaveAs = "new_text";
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});


window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileNameToSaveAs);
}
```

this peace of code creates a file and ask for user to save the file i.e download prompt.

How do i get this done automatically.

In webBrowser control it asks for save dialog box. i want to prevent this.

Basically whatever text the user selects in the webBrowser control and press a button copy the file with selected text is to be downloaded

thank you

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot download a file in a browser without the user being notified via the save/download dialog. Imagine how big a security risk this would be if files could be saved to the local machine by malicious coders.

Comment: google chrome does it :). it just shows the downloaded file at the bottom of the browser without any popup or dialog box

Comment: Exactly, that's the notification. People can also set the browser to always ask where to save the file - as is the default in most.

Comment: ok.... so how do i do the same in webBrowser control. just notify the download instead of some dialogue box

Comment: That's my point, you can't - it's controlled by the browser.

Comment: ok.... any other options other than is ?? like using clipboard or something else